# splice objects from array and move those elements to a different element within array without mutating original

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

This code does kinda what I need but it mutates the original array and that is not what I want. I know this happens because I'm using `splice` and `push`.
This object has every day of the week as key and each key has the opening and closing time of the store.

Everything is normal until the `friday` key which has only the `open` time object and the `close` one is on the `saturday` key(because the store closes the next day), same thing happens for `saturday` and `sunday`.
What I do is move each object to its corresponding day key but I want to achieve this without mutating the original object.

What am I missing to achieve that?

```js
const days = {
  "monday": [{
      "day": "monday",
      "type": "open",
      "value": 43200
    },
    {
      "day": "monday",
      "type": "close",
      "value": 75600
    }
  ],
  "tuesday": [{
      "day": "tuesday",
      "type": "open",
      "value": 43200
    },
    {
      "day": "tuesday",
      "type": "close",
      "value": 75600
    }
  ],
  "wednesday": [{
      "day": "wednesday",
      "type": "open",
      "value": 43200
    },
    {
      "day": "wednesday",
      "type": "close",
      "value": 75600
    }
  ],
  "thursday": [{
      "day": "thursday",
      "type": "open",
      "value": 43200
    },
    {
      "day": "thursday",
      "type": "close",
      "value": 75600
    }
  ],
  "friday": [{
    "day": "friday",
    "type": "open",
    "value": 36000
  }],
  "saturday": [{
      "day": "friday",
      "type": "close",
      "value": 3600
    },
    {
      "day": "saturday",
      "type": "open",
      "value": 36000
    }
  ],
  "sunday": [{
      "day": "saturday",
      "type": "close",
      "value": 3600
    },
    {
      "day": "sunday",
      "type": "open",
      "value": 43200
    },
    {
      "day": "sunday",
      "type": "close",
      "value": 75600
    }
  ]
}

const result = Object.entries(days).map(([k, v], i) => {
  if (k == "friday") {
    days[k].push(days.saturday.splice(0, 1));
    //console.log(days[k])
  } else if (k == "saturday") {
    days[k].push(days.sunday.splice(0, 1));
    //console.log(days[k])
  }
  return {
    [k]: v
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Have you tried Array.prototype.slice?

Comment: not sure how to apply it in this case, can you show an example?

Comment: Unlike splice, slice does not mutate the array in-place. It returns a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take all of the inner objects and use their `day` properties to rebuild the overall object from scratch:

```js
const days = {"monday": [{"day": "monday","type": "open","value": 43200},{"day": "monday","type": "close","value": 75600}],"tuesday": [{"day": "tuesday","type": "open","value": 43200},{"day": "tuesday","type": "close","value": 75600}],"wednesday": [{"day": "wednesday","type": "open","value": 43200},{"day": "wednesday","type": "close","value": 75600}],"thursday": [{"day": "thursday","type": "open","value": 43200},{"day": "thursday","type": "close","value": 75600}],"friday": [{"day": "friday","type": "open","value": 36000}],"saturday": [{"day": "friday","type": "close","value": 3600},{"day": "saturday","type": "open","value": 36000}],"sunday": [{"day": "saturday","type": "close","value": 3600},{"day": "sunday","type": "open","value": 43200},{"day": "sunday","type": "close","value": 75600}]};

const result = Object.values(days).flat().reduce((acc, o) => {
    (acc[o.day] ??= []).push(o);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```